# Groovy StreamingTemplateEngine gives error with withCredentials function

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I created the Jenkins pipeline which calls below function... It creates a Template variable with StreamingTemplateEngine object... But it gives an error

```groovy
def call() {
    def name = "abc"
    def binding = [
        firstname: "Grace",
        lastname: "Hopper",
    ]

    def text = 'Dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname}'
    def template = new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)

    print template.make(binding)

    def response = template.make(binding)

    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Token', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
        println("test")
        println(response)
    }
}
```

Above code prints response successfully first time but at the end it gives below error

```
an exception which occurred:
        in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
        in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@3678d955
        in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef.capture
        in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosureDef@23a3d63c
        in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsClosure.def
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@6d8ad313
        in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@76f2b368
        in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@76f2b368
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine$StreamingTemplate
```

If I remove withCredentials function then it works fine.

Comment: Don't call twice the same method 'make(binding)' but rather 'print response'

Comment: Not serializable usually means Java can't write your object as a string to store it in memory. Your object must implement serializable interface which implies some conditions : a unique ID and each attribute is itself serializable. Don't know what your with credentials method is about but it has a set argument?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins Pipeline runs Groovy code in the continuation-passing style (`groovy-cps`). It expects that every local variable is `Serializable` so it can safely serialize every computation and restore it in case of, e.g., Jenkins restart.

In case of using a non-serializable object, Jenkins Pipeline offers `@NonCPS` annotation that can be used with a method to mark that this part of code is not serializable and shouldn't be transformed to the CPS code interpretation.

> *"Pipeline scripts may mark designated methods with the annotation `@NonCPS`. These are then compiled normally (except for sandbox security checks), and so behave much like “binary” methods from the Java Platform, Groovy runtime, or Jenkins core or plugin code. `@NonCPS` methods may safely use non-`Serializable` objects as local variables, though they should not accept nonserializable parameters or return or store nonserializable values. You may not call regular (CPS-transformed) methods, or Pipeline steps, from a `@NonCPS` method, so they are best used for performing some calculations before passing a summary back to the main script. Note in particular that `@Overrides` of methods defined in binary classes, such as Object.toString(), should in general be marked `@NonCPS` since it will commonly be binary code calling them."*
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin#technical-design</sup>

You can extract `StreamingTemplateEngine` part to the separate `@NonCPS` method that expects a template as text, and a map of bindings. Something like this should be safe to use:

```groovy
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

def call() {
    def name = "abc"
    def binding = [
        firstname: "Grace",
        lastname: "Hopper",
    ]

    def text = 'Dear <% out.print firstname %> ${lastname}'

    def response = parseTemplate(text, binding)

    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Token', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
        println(response)
    }
}

@NonCPS
String parseTemplate(String text, Map bindings) {
    new groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)
        .make(bindings)
        .toString()
}
```

Comment: I have already tested @NonCPS annotation but it throws null pointer exception..

Comment: What the NullPointerException says exactly? Which reference is null? The `java.io.NotSerializableException` is thrown because you mix non-serializable objects in the CPS mode. That is the root cause of the problem you mentioned in the question. NPE is probably caused by something else.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.addBodyEndFlowNode(CpsBodyExecution.java:407)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.access$800(CpsBodyExecution.java:65)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$FailureAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:353)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.launch(CpsBodyExecution.java:166)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyInvoker.launch(CpsBodyInvoker.java:182)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsB